# numpy element-wise multiplication of matrices 3d * 3d = 4d

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a numpy ndarray A of dimension m * n * x and another numpy ndarray B of dimension m * n * y. 
I want to multiply them and get an ndarray C of dimensions m * n * x * y in the following way:

```
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        C[:,:, i, j] = numpy.multiply(A[:, :, i], B[:, :, j])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
C = A[:, :, :, numpy.newaxis] * B[:, :, numpy.newaxis, :]
```

Insert new length-1 axes at the appropriate points in `A` and `B`'s shapes and apply broadcasted multiplication.